# How to establish PAN in embedded device

Tags: linux, bluetooth, pan, tethering, ppp

Hi I want to share the Internet of GPRS/3G using Bluetooth tethering or PAN from my embedded device to other devices,to do so what are the steps i need to follow i.e how can i establish a interface between ppp0 and pan0 so that internet can be shared.
What are the requirements to make this possible,my embedded device contains LINUX OS with kernel-3.X and BlueZ-3.11.X
Please guide me the needful if possible from scratch.

Thanks in advance